# wcf service to upload/download large files raises exception if returned stream is null

Tags: wcf, large-files

i'm writing a wcf service to handle large files, i've followed the rules explained on msdn and found around on web. The service download method returns a stream and calls a business logic object which searches for documents into an ecm . the ecm api raises an exception when there aren't matching documents and the bl object returns a null stream.
The server side code executes without exceptions, but when the response reaches the client i got a System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly . 
I've searched the web and all problems related to that exception refer to excessive size of returned values , while i'm having the opposite problem. My question is there's a specific way to handle null return streams ? Is something related to the service or client configuration ? at the moment i'm returning an empty stream , but it doesn't look a smart solution .
Below i've addded sever-client configuration and the trace of the wcf service.

---

Server configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpBindingConf" transferMode="StreamedResponse" messageEncoding="Text"
          maxBufferSize="5000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" 
         closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <!--<security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>-->
      <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="5000000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="FileNetLoaderService.FileNetLoaderServiceBehavior" name="FileNetLoaderService.FileNetLoaderService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpBindingConf"
      contract="FileNetLoaderService.FileNetLoaderService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="FileNetLoaderService.FileNetLoaderServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!--<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />-->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

---

client configuration :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_FileNetLoaderService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="StreamedResponse"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2436/FileNetLoaderService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_FileNetLoaderService"
            contract="localFilenetLoaderService.FileNetLoaderService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_FileNetLoaderService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

---

trace log

```
<TraceData><DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-IT/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>TestForm.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
at TestForm.localFilenetLoaderService.FileNetLoaderService.downLoad(String guid, String CodiceAzienda, String TipoLavorazione)
at TestForm.localFilenetLoaderService.FileNetLoaderServiceClient.downLoad(String guid, String CodiceAzienda, String TipoLavorazione)
at TestForm.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp; m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp; msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
at TestForm.Program.Main()
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)</ExceptionString>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

---

a piece of code

server

```
System.IO.Stream s = myDBRead.GetDocumentStream(guid, out filename);
                if (s == null)
                    return new MemoryStream();
                return s;
```

client

```
try
                {
                    object ss = client.downLoad("297584cf-29c2-4ad5-be37-5219ad04cb74", "5728", "Effetti");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to my question is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ead674c2-dcce-4dd5-8237-3a3ce2009905)

just my lack of knwoledge of stream class